# Named regular expression group "(?P<group_name>regexp)": what does "P" stand for?

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

In Python, the `(?P<group_name>…)` [syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) allows one to refer to the matched string through its name:

```
>>> import re
>>> match = re.search('(?P<name>.*) (?P<phone>.*)', 'John 123456')
>>> match.group('name')
'John'
```

What does "P" stand for?  I could not find any hint in the [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

I would love to get ideas about how to help my students remember this syntax. Knowing what "P" does stand for (or might stand for) would be useful.

Comment: `P` stands for `Placeholder`.

Comment: @kev: seems like that should be an answer?

Comment: Since guesses are appropriate, I conjecture that Ken Thompson is a hippie sympathizer and the "P" stand for "Patchouli".

Comment: This question has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Groups".

Comment: Just a reminder: The [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) module supports naming groups with both the `(?<name>...)` syntax as well as the current `(?P<name>...)`.

Comment: By the way, if you use `match.groups` (with an `s`) you will silently get a tuple of *all* groups -_-
    `groups('name')` => `('John', '123456')` when what you actually wanted was
     `group('name')` => `'John'`

I hope this saves someone somewhere some time(s).

Comment: one word to summarize "stupid P"

Comment: @szmoore I just burned like twenty minutes on that exact thing. So, you didn't save me any time, but I got some commiseration.

Comment: See also `groupdict()`

Answer (score 423, accepted):

Since we're all guessing, I might as well give mine: I've always thought it stood for Python.  That may sound pretty stupid -- what, P for Python?! -- but in my defense, I vaguely remembered [this thread](http://markmail.org/message/oyezhwvefvotacc3) [emphasis mine]:

> Subject:  Claiming (?P...) regex syntax extensions
>
> From: Guido van Rossum (gui...@CNRI.Reston.Va.US)
>
> Date: Dec 10, 1997 3:36:19 pm
>
> I have an unusual request for the Perl developers (those that develop
>   the Perl language).  I hope this (perl5-porters) is the right list.  I
>   am cc'ing the Python string-sig because it is the origin of most of
>   the work I'm discussing here.
>
> You are probably aware of Python.  I am Python's creator; I am
>   planning to release a next "major" version, Python 1.5, by the end of
>   this year.  I hope that Python and Perl can co-exist in years to come;
>   cross-pollination can be good for both languages.  (I believe Larry
>   had a good look at Python when he added objects to Perl 5; O'Reilly
>   publishes books about both languages.)
>
> As you may know, Python 1.5 adds a new regular expression module that
>   more closely matches Perl's syntax.  We've tried to be as close to the
>   Perl syntax as possible within Python's syntax.  However, the regex
>   syntax has some Python-specific extensions, which all begin with (?P .
>   Currently there are two of them:
>
> `(?P<foo>...)` Similar to regular grouping parentheses, but the text
>   matched by the group is accessible after the match has been performed,
>   via the symbolic group name "foo".
>
> `(?P=foo)` Matches the same string as that matched by the group named 
>   "foo".  Equivalent to \1, \2, etc. except that the group is referred
>   to by name, not number.
>
> I hope that this Python-specific extension won't conflict with any
>   future Perl extensions to the Perl regex syntax.  If you have plans to
>   use (?P, please let us know as soon as possible so we can resolve the
>   conflict.  **Otherwise, it would be nice if the (?P syntax could be
>   permanently reserved for Python-specific syntax extensions.**  (Is
>   there  some kind of registry of extensions?)

to which Larry Wall replied:

> [...]   There's no registry as of now--yours is the first request from
>   outside perl5-porters, so it's a pretty low-bandwidth activity. 
>   (Sorry it was even lower last week--I was off in New York at Internet
>   World.)
>
> Anyway, as far as I'm concerned, you may certainly have 'P' with my
>   blessing. (Obviously Perl doesn't need the 'P' at this point. :-) [...]

So I don't know what the original choice of P was motivated by -- pattern? placeholder? penguins? -- but you can understand why I've always associated it with Python.  Which considering that (1) I don't like regular expressions and avoid them wherever possible, and (2) this thread happened fifteen years ago, is kind of odd.

Comment: "Python-specific extension" perhaps?

Comment: Wow, you did find some good and relevant piece of historical data, here!  My interpretation of Guido's post is that "P" stands for "Python-specific extensions".

Comment: Yep, that looks definitive to me.  So it's ironic that Perl and PCRE initially copied the syntax, just because Python was the first flavor to support named captures.  But they also support the `(?<group_name>…)` syntax, which seems to be the most popular--even Java supports it now.

Comment: Python / Proprietary, python does seem likely

Comment: +1 This is one of the best awkward answers which is well defended :). At first, I thought this is too stupid. But in the end, I totally agreed.

Comment: I love that even the creator of Python uses bizarre arcane syntax when Perl is involved, and the Perl community is totally fine with that. If you tried to add Perl-specific extensions/syntax to Python, there would be blood on the streets.

Comment: confirmed even here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html

Comment: @KeithRipley  While the vast majority of us are tied to python given its ubiquity (and great libraries) some of us (including myself) would be happier to live under the "many ways to do things" philosophy of Perl if given a choice.

Answer (score 40):

Python Extension.  From the Python Docs:

> The solution chosen by the Perl developers was to use (?...) as the
> extension syntax. ? immediately after a parenthesis was a syntax error
> because the ? would have nothing to repeat, so this didn’t introduce
> any compatibility problems. The characters immediately after the ?
> indicate what extension is being used, so (?=foo) is one thing (a
> positive lookahead assertion) and (?:foo) is something else (a
> non-capturing group containing the subexpression foo).
>
> Python supports several of Perl’s extensions and adds an extension
> syntax to Perl’s extension syntax.**If the first character after the
> question mark is a P, you know that it’s an extension that’s specific
> to Python**

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Comment: Well spotted! This confirms DSM's feeling.

Answer (score 21):

Pattern!  The group names a (sub)pattern for later use in the regex.  See [the documentation here](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) for details about how such groups are used.

Comment: +1: This is a good mnemonic device: `(?P<name>…)` is "pattern `name`". Everything is a pattern, though, in a regexp, so it is kind of strange to only label `(?P<…>…)` groups as patterns.  This will do, though, for my students. :)

Comment: @EOL don't teach students false things. They are harder to shred off when you reach for exactness than you think. Eg. some, for me, takes years multiple of `5`. Paradoxically, it's encouraged to speak casually, just always be very clear and explicit about it - eg. tell your previous comment in full length to your students (revising perhaps the very last sentence;).)