# How django's url regex work

Tags: python, regex, django

In the following url:

```
(r'^videos/view/(?P<video_id>[^/]+)/$'
```

- What does the `r'` mean/do?
- What does the `?P` mean/do?
- How is the `<video_id>` escaped by the regex?

In other words, how is the above different than:

```
'^/videos/view/[^/]+/$'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`r''` marks a raw string, so that you don't have to double-escape backslashes. In this case, it's not necessary because there aren't any, but a lot of people always do it for regexes anyway.

`(?P<video_id>[^/]+)` is a Python extension to regexes that "names" that capture group `video_id`. In Django, this means that the match is sent to the view as a keyword argument `video_id`; if you did `view/([^/]+)/$`, it would be sent as the first positional argument. In your example, though, there are no parens at all, meaning that the view wouldn't get any arguments!

Comment: Thanks, what does the actual `?P` mean, or is this the non-regex "python extension" that you mentioned?

Comment: The `?P` is just part of the syntax saying it's a named group. If you left it out, i.e. `(<video_id>[^/]+)`, it'd look for a literal `<video_id>` in the string. More details [in the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) (search for "?P<", there's no direct link).

Comment: [what does “P” stand for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059673/named-regular-expression-group-pgroup-nameregexp-what-does-p-stand-for)