# Match multiple regexes in one iteration of a file

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a big file.
And I have n regexes.

I want to match all n regexes against the file but by going over the file only once. So here is my pseudo code:

Here I run the loop for all regexes for every line.

```
f = open("file.txt")
for line in f:
   for regex in regexes:
      m = re.search(regex, line)
      if m is not None:
          # do something
```

Another pseudo code, where I write n `if-elif` statements

```
f = open("file.txt")
for line in f:
     if re.search(regex1, line)
        # do something1
     elif re.search(regex2, line)
        # do something2
     elif re.search(regex3, line)
        # do something3 
     ...
     else:
        pass
```

I don't like either approaches. What is a better way to do this in python?

Comment: Can you give an example of a line to match and the regexes you would match it against?

Comment: A dictionary: keys are your regexes and values are the functions to apply given a regex.

Comment: Is it important for you to know **which** regexp matched, or just that there was a match?

Comment: @Błotosmętek It is important to know which matched. Do my code examples not make that clear ? If not, I can update them.

Comment: @abc, These somethings of yours need to be defined as function and get mapped to their regexes via a python dictionary. That doesn't sound like a better idea to you?

Comment: @Abdou Yes that is one other approach. But how do I avoid the loop for each line ?

Comment: If you want to both know the matched regex and have access to the corresponding function/operation, you will have to have a nested loop.

Comment: I've never actually used named regex group names, so I can't give solid advice, but this question might be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059673/named-regular-expression-group-pgroup-nameregexp-what-does-p-stand-for

Answer (score -1):

Use one regex to rule them all:

```
new_regex = '(' + ')|('.join(my_list_of_regexes) + ')'
```

You probably wanna use string formatting instead of the `+`s  but you get the point.

Comment: And that is exactly why I asked if it is important which of the regexps matched. This solution won't let you know.

Comment: @Błotosmętek Exactly.