# How to get individual values from a string seperated by commas

Tags: python

I am reading a file using:

```
def readFile():
    file = open('Rules.txt', 'r')
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        rulesList.append(line)
```

rulesList:

```
['\n', "Rule(F1, HTTPS TCP, ['ip', 'ip'], ['www.google.ca', '8.8.8.8'], 443)\n", '\n', "Rule(F2, HTTPS TCP, ['ip', 'ip'], ['75.2.18.233'], 443)\n", '\n']
```

My file looks like:

```
Rule(F1, HTTPS TCP, ['ip', 'ip'], ['www.google.ca', '8.8.8.8'], 443)

Rule(F2, HTTPS TCP, ['ip', 'ip'], ['ip'], 443)
```

I would like to feed the values to a class I created

```
class Rule:
    def __init__(self, flowNumber, protocol, port, fromIP=[], toIP=[]):
        self.flowNumber = flowNumber
        self.protocol = protocol
        self.port = port
        self.fromIP = fromIP
        self.toIP = toIP

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'\nRule({self.flowNumber}, {self.protocol}, {self.fromIP}, {self.toIP}, {self.port})'

 newRule = Rule(currentFlowNum, currentProtocol, currentPort, currentFromIP, currentToIP)
```

to get an output such as:

```
[F1, HTTPS TCP, ['ip', 'ip'], ['www.google.ca', '8.8.8.8'], 443]
```

or be able to assign these values to a variable like:

```
currentFlowNum = F1, currentProtocol = 'HTTPS TCP' , currentPort = 443, currentFromIP = ['ip', 'ip'], currentToIP = ['www.google.ca', '8.8.8.8']
```

I tried:

```
for rule in rulesList:
        if rule !='\n':
            tmp = rule.split(',')
            print(tmp)
```

tmp:

```
['Rule(F1', ' HTTPS TCP', " ['ip'", " 'ip']", " ['www.google.ca'", " '8.8.8.8']", ' 443)\n']
['Rule(F2', ' HTTPS TCP', " ['ip'", " 'ip']", " ['ip']", ' 443)\n']
```

Is there a way to not split the commas between [] i.e. I would like the output to look like:

```
['Rule(F1', ' HTTPS TCP', " ['ip','ip']", " ['www.google.ca', '8.8.8.8']", ' 443)\n']
['Rule(F2', ' HTTPS TCP', " ['ip','ip']", " ['ip']", ' 443)\n']
```

Comment: There is and it requires you to write your own parser. What would be more better imo is using a standard format like json or yaml

Comment: @Vulwsztyn do you mean converting the array to json before saving into a file?

Comment: You could probably used named regex groups to parse this, perhaps capturing the lists and doing further processing on them afterwards. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/10059673/2958070 for a simple example of named regex groups.

 Also note, you don't want your `Rule` class to use `[]` as a default argument in `fromIP` and `toIP`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/366422/2958070 about that

Comment: @ritvikseth if converting to json before you save the file is an option then emphatically yes, that is many orders of magnitude better than trying to parse this format

Comment: @Ben thank you for your comment I will check the links

Comment: @DeanMacGregor yes that is an option for me I will try that thank you

Comment: @Swifty if the json idea does not work I will try regex tbh I am very bad at regex lol, thank you for your comment

Comment: I removed my comment because your rules already are separated elements of the list; I'll rethink it later :). But yeah, saving as json or csv (separated by ; instead of ,) would makes things simpler.

Comment: BTW, there's no need for the `for line in lines:` loop. Just do `rulesList = file.readlines()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have control over how the data in the file is stored and can replace the single quotes (`'`) with double quotes (`"`) to make the "list" structures valid JSON, you *could* use RegExp for this.

**A word of caution**: unless you are absolutely sure that the format you'll be reading will largely remain the same and is rather inflexible, you're better off storing this data in a more well-established format (as mentioned in the comments) like JSON, YAML, etc. There are **so** many edge cases that could happen here that rolling your own parser like this objectively suboptimal.

```
import re
import json

def readFile():
    file = open('Rules.txt', 'r')
    myRules = []
    for line in file.readlines():
        match = re.match(r'Rule\((?P<flow_number>[^,]+),\s(?P<protocol>[^,]+),\s(?P<from_ip>\[[^\]]+\]),\s(?P<to_ip>\[[^\]]+\]),\s(?P<port>[^,)]+)\)', line)
        if match:
          myRules.append(Rule(match.group('flow_number'), match.group('protocol'), match.group('port'), json.loads(match.group('from_ip')), json.loads(match.group('to_ip'))))

    return myRules


print(readFile())
# Returns:
# [
#  Rule(F1, HTTPS TCP, ['ip', 'ip'], ['www.google.ca', '8.8.8.8'], 443), 
#  Rule(F2, HTTPS TCP, ['ip', 'ip'], ['ip'], 443)]
```

<sup>[Repl.it](https://replit.com/@esqew/FantasticAttentivePolygons) | [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/NtNXoV/1)</sup>

Comment: wow, nicely done.

Comment: @esqew thank you for your solution, I have accepted the ans but as I have 100s of rules I think the better approach to my problem would be to go with json. Hope this solution helps someone in future